# Receiving an error when installing bootstrap4

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to install django-bootstrap4 on Python, but I'm not sure how to deal with this error. Issued the command, 'pip install django-bootstrap4' in my virtual environment.

error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SCHEME_KEYS' from 'pip._internal.models.scheme' (c:\users\chawa\onedrive\desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\models\scheme.py)
```

Python version - 3.8.5

Django version - 3.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the author(Eric Matthes) of the course, it seems that there was an issue with pip. The installation was successful after upgrading the version of Python and rebuilding the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Run :

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then

```
pip install django-bootstrap4
```

It is most likely than your PIP does not match package requirements, you can also try the following command :

```
pip3 install django-bootstrap4
```

Comment: Just tried it, it's still giving me the same error

Comment: Are you using conda ?

Comment: Not that I know of, I'm just following through the Python crash course 2nd ed book. Haven't touched on conda

Answer (score -1):

Better to use CDN version of Bootstrap 4, just paste this in your .html file

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_get_started.asp

Comment: OP ask to install a specific package with Django, your workaround does not answer the orignal question